# Question About C# Chart Data's Positioning

Tags: c#, charts

[image]

Can I set chart data's position by it's X Axis?

for example, 500 is 0.25% of 200,000 so i want this 500 bar located it's 0.25% position, but i can't find an option for data position. is there any option of positioning? or can i access it's position directly?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what it is you need? Code, strategy, theory, etc? Also provide some sample code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The x-values will be used to place the columns if they are added as numbers or dates. You can influence the total placement a little by setting axis minimum and maximum. Beyond that columns and bars are placed automatically. I suspect you add them as strings? Do not do that! Or you have turned on series.XValuesAreIndexed. Don't do that either!

Comment: it solved, thanks. it was my first question in stackoverflow so this question wasn't good, sorry'bout that. it'll be better next.